# Can XTerm do all the things Terminal can do?

Tags: command-line, xterm

Is XTerm able to do all of the things the regular terminal can do?

Comment: What is it that you actually want to do?

Answer (score 6):

**Yes and no**. As far as commands go, it's the same since it uses the same shell (bash) that every other terminal on your system does.

**But** `xterm` is a basic terminal emulator which does not support features you may be used to with the regular (gnome-) terminal such as multiple tabs, etc. Other things such as changing fonts is also more difficult (people often find the xterm default font too tiny.)

The reason for this lack of features is that xterm depends only on the core X server, unlike gnome-terminal and the others. It will run even on an Ubuntu that has no graphical environment installed, and uses very little memory (but that doesn't matter unless you have a very old computer)

Note that you can get additional features within xterm by using a text-mode session manager such as *byobu* (screen), but for most users it's easier to stick to gnome-terminal or alternatives such as xfce4-terminal, etc.

Comment: As far as commands go, it's all the same, though?

Comment: Yes--it's the same in that respect. Please see edit at beginning of the answer and if this helped you out, don't forget to accept it as the answer (tick mark on left) so that it's marked as closed and future readers can see the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer yes.

Longer answer [Xterm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xterm) is a [terminal emulator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_emulator), as is [gnome-terminal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Terminal).
gnome-terminal is more configurable then xterm in that you have greater control over colours can assign keyboard shortcuts etc.
But what you type into the terminal is exactly the same no matter which terminal emulator you use.
What makes the difference in the capabilities of what you can do with the terminal is not the emulator, but the [shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell)
There are a number of options of shell most common is [bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29), another option is [fish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fish_%28Unix_shell%29)